# Submitting ReCaptcha With Selenium and ImageTyperz

Tags: java, selenium, recaptcha

I'm writing a program that fills out a sign up page, completes the captcha on the page, and then submits the form.

I wrote this in Java using Selenium and ImageTyperz API.

I can't figure out how to import the result I get from ImageTyperz

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.textnow.com/signup");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstname']")).sendKeys(FirstNames);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='lastname']")).sendKeys(lastNames2);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys(FirstNames + "drop" + Num);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys(FirstNames + lastNames + "1998");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys(FirstNames + lastNames + Num + "@hotmail.com");

ImageTyperzAPI C = new ImageTyperzAPI("key");
C.set_user_and_password("user", "password");
String balance = C.account_balance();
System.out.println(String.format("Balance: %s", balance));
String page_url = "https://www.textnow.com/signup";
String sitekey = driver.findElementByClassName("g-recaptcha").getAttribute("data-sitekey");
String recaptcha_id = C.submit_recaptcha(page_url, sitekey);
while(C.in_progress(recaptcha_id))
{
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10); 
    System.out.println("Waiting For Respone");
}

// completed at this point
String recaptcha_response = C.retrieve_captcha(recaptcha_id);
String g_response_code = C.retrieve_captcha(recaptcha_id);
System.out.println(g_response_code);
```

Now I need to import the result I get from ImageTyperz. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using sendKeys with recaptcha_response on the textbox where the user has to type the captcha?

Comment: It’s a recaptcha so it’s one that you click on the pictures